# Toast is not showing in posting tweet

Tags: android, twitter, toast

This is my code when the user click the share button.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_login :
                loginToTwitter();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_share:
                status = "I'm riding at taxi name: " + operator.getText().toString() + "\n" + "With the plate number of: " + plate.getText().toString() + "\n" +
                        shareEditText.getText().toString();
                if(status.trim().length() > 0) {
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Message is empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2Activity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Posting to Twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String status = params[0];

            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

                String access_token = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                String acces_token_secret = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, acces_token_secret);

                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(status);

                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted to Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            shareEditText.setText("");
        }
    }
```

When the content message is successfully tweeted the toast that i assign in the OnPostExecute is not working. Even the tweet is not sent the toast is not showing. I dont know why. I cant identify if my tweet is being tweeted or not. but when i try it, it successfully tweeted but it doesnt show toast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `show()`

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted to Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and for better coding use context variable or activityName.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: as he is showing it outside of the onCreate he can't use getApplicationContext(), insted if that he need to use this. am i ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted to Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Toast is not showing because you have not called `show()` method .

like :

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted to Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```